# Celery Logs into file

Tags: python, celery

Can someone please help and tell me how to get the celery task debug details to a log file? I have a requirement to have the details of celery task logged into a .log file.

Can you please make some suggestions on how this can be done without impacting the performance of the task?

Answer (score 57):

**Celery** have specific option `-f --logfile` which you can use:

```
-f LOGFILE, --logfile=LOGFILE
                    Path to log file. If no logfile is specified, stderr
                    is used.
```

To get information about other options, just use `celery worker --help`. If just want want celery worker with logging to file, your command may look like this:

```
celery worker -f <filename>
python manage.py celery worker -f <filename> -> in django-celery case
```

There are a lot of logging options for Celery you may need:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply,it was my bad that i didn't explain in details.I have my celery working running,for me I need separate logs to be written on the worker tasks and also in the code that invokes the task. Will writing the logs have performance impact.

Comment: @user2479840, you can separate logs by configuring loggers to different files http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html .Perfomance impact is minor, unless you are writing 100K logs in a minute.

Comment: The above answer is nice. But in addition to that, you can configure the log file in the python project itself using `logging` module

Answer (score 16):

If you want to log everything, you can use the following command

> -f celery.logs

You can also specify different log levels as well. For suppose if you want log warning and errors add like following.

> --loglevel=warning -f celery.logs

Comment: Whether this do the Log rotation or it will keep growing on single file